# Connection call in stop life cycle method

Tags: codenameone

I want to call the connection even after the app goes to background or device screen is off. I think onStop method comes in action when screen goes off. I've called connectionRequest inside a timer in stop() method but it is not working.

```
public void start() {
    if (current != null) {
        current.show();
        return;
    }

    hi = new Form("My app", BoxLayout.y());
    hi.show();
 }

public void stop() {
    new UITimer(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("fghfhfghgf ");
            Connection c = new Connection();
            c.connectionMethod();
        }
    }).schedule(10000, true, hi);
    current = getCurrentForm();
    if (current instanceof Dialog) {
        ((Dialog) current).dispose();
        current = getCurrentForm();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called background fetch and is discussed in the developer guide I think in the miscellaneous section https://www.codenameone.com/manual/misc-features.html